# Reduce font-size when long word overflows horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, function, loops

I have long titles that sometimes slightly overflow the window on small screens, so I made a script that reduces the font-size of the title until it fits its container **only when the title overflows its container**… It works but I'm sure a lighter solution could be found.

```
function adaptFontSize(titles) {
    $(titles).each(function() {
        var title = $(this),
            reducedFontSize,
            counter = 0;
        if (title[0].scrollWidth <= title.innerWidth()) { // if title <= container
            title.css('font-size', ''); // remove previously added font-size
        }
        while (title[0].scrollWidth > title.innerWidth() && counter < 20) { // while title > container
            var fontSize = reducedFontSize || parseInt(title.css('font-size')); // current title font-size
            reducedFontSize = Math.floor((fontSize - fontSize / 20) * 100) / 100; // reduce the font-size
            title.css('font-size', reducedFontSize + 'px'); // apply the reduced font-size
            counter++ // counter to limit the loop in case title[0].scrollWidth is not supported
        }
    });
}
```

or here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Raoulito/pek7b3mr/12/

> My problem comes when I try to apply the script on `$(window).resize()`. It actually *works* but I can feel that the process is heavy. It has to work in both ways:
>
> - reduce the font-size if the title's too wide,
> - increase the font-size when the window gets resized wider, **until the title reaches its original font-size**.

Here are some of steps I tried but did not manage to achieve:

- that it does not fire the function all the way through at each pixel the window is resized, but rather wait until it stops resizing.
- when the window gets resized wider, only target—among the titles which are smaller than the window—the ones that have already been resized and might need to get bigger again.

So I'm looking for a way to fix these, or alternatively for a way of reaching this in a much more efficient way.

Comment: You could try media queries for a css only solution.

Comment: But 99% of my titles have a good size, only 1% overflows. I'm looking for a solution only for these last ones, and that can be consistent on many width of small screens.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [VW unit](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).

`1vw` equals `1%` of the view width, so it's a simple css only solution which works in all modern browsers.

https://jsfiddle.net/pek7b3mr/8/

```css
body {
    margin: 1em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

div {
    background-color: yellow;
    font-size: 5vw;
 margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 012356789</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposal, but it's not actually that: I need a fixed font-size when the title is smaller than the window, and only reduce the font-size in the case the title is wider than the window.

Comment: You would need javascript for that... you can use media queries to set a minimum width to apply this rule.

Comment: That would be too easy to be fun!

Comment: Well the easiest way is the one that will hurt your browser the least.